# How to avoid asking for Notification permission in Incognito mode after Chrome 76 update? Notification rejected after how many seconds?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, incognito-mode

I have a use case where I show a black overlay with some helper texts to allow or reject the Web Push Notification.

```
this.showOverlay();
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
   ...
   this.hideOverlay();
   ...
})
```

Earlier I was not executing this code in Incognito mode. But now since Google has closed all the loopholes to detect Incognito mode, I am getting an overlay for few seconds and then its disappearing automatically.
Actually in Incognito, Chrome is not waiting for the User to allow or reject it and rather it is rejecting it by itself but after delay of some second.

So the question is:
1. Can I stop asking for the permission in Incognito mode? (seems not possible)
2. Is there any fixed time duration after which Chrome rejects the permission?

You can see this issue in any websites which shows overlay while asking for Notification permission in Incognito mode. eg., https://www.facebook.com

Comment: Well the real problem is stupid design. Why show overlay when asking for notifications permission? The browser shows the permission dialog, there's no GUI operation required from you. If you want to inform user about an option to use notifications, maybe just give them an option to trigger the whole thing via a button instead of pestering them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way get it working is to cancel using custom popups before the permission is requested. Or do some timing like require permission and show the custom popup if the promise isn't resolved in a couple of seconds.

Browsers aren't interested to let you know you're in incognito so it's a problem indeed.  And it's a problem as e.g. we'd like to explain the user what notifications we're going to send him. As many sites offer news notifications and some worthless updates many users just click 'Block' as soon as they see the permission popup. ...and aren't notified about incoming messages or any other vital info on our site. In this case custom popup delay won't help much but it mostly depends on user. So may be a solution in some limited cases.

As for the time duration I didn't notice any difference: it doesn't resolve the promise instantly but takes time as if the user denied. It may also be affected by different reasons like the user device performance or so.